# Is it best practice to have a RecyclerView inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my case I have a list of objects and each object has a list of other objects, like:

```kotlin
class Parent(val title, val childs: List<Child>)
class Child(val title)
```

The above code is an example and there are a lot more fields to implement, like images (for the sake of the question lets keep it simple).

Now what I want is:

- To use custom layout for both parent and child items
- The child items must be displayed inside the parent item

Based on the above, I decided to use a `RecyclerView` inside a `RecyclerView`.

Some other options are:

- The parent `RecyclerView` will be scrollable but the child `RecyclerView` will have fixed height (so there is no need to implement nested scrolling).
- Both `RecyclerView`s have a vertical orientation.
- When clicking the parent item the visibility of the child `RecyclerView` will be toggled (this is not very relevant to the actual question, but just to get an idea of what I have in mind).

Using my poor skills, I would initialize the child `RecyclerView` inside the parent `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` method (of the parent `RecyclerView.Adapter`) I would assign the `LayoutManager` and initialize/assign the child `RecyclerView.Adapter` to the child `RecyclerView`.

I would also implement a `Listener` that when clicking a child item, a callback will be called containing two parameters, the index of parent and index of child.

I know how to implement what I described above, the actual question is if this is "correct"
or better say, the best practice.

As far as I can think, this implementation seems dirty and not very optimized (maybe I am wrong). I want you to explain me if there is better way to implement what I described above (with examples if possible). If not, providing an explanation why there is no better way will be also useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to go on about this.

- The method I would use is the one you described above, however, you should be careful so that you "set up" `Child`'s `RecyclerView` in the *init* block of the `Parent`'s `ViewHolder`, so you don't do too much work on the binding process of the `Parent`'s items binding process. And, I would use this method, because it is easier to implement the:

> When clicking the parent item the visibility of the child RecyclerView will be toggled (this is not very relevant to the actual question, but just to get an idea of what I have in mind).

feature, so this is kinda relevant, in the aspect that you can have a harder time to implement it using the next method.

- Another way of doing this, is by implementing an adapter that takes into consideration the `RecyclerView.Adapter`'s `viewType`, which you can use to distinguish between `Parent` and `Child` model types so you use the corresponding `ViewHolder` for each type, making the list look like a list with clear sections, the section headers of which are the `Parent`'s model. This method is great for making a list with sections, however, making a toggle functionality requires careful considerations on how you want to hide the `ViewHolders` by looking for them specifically or using extra variables to save the state of the sections and careful conditions on the `RecyclerView.Adapter`'s `ViewHolder`'s ***bind()*** method, which may or may not cause a headache.

So basically I would use the first method. Hope this helps!

Comment: The second one is tricky to implement and we cannot add animation. I will probably follow the first one and try to initialize whatever possible inside the parent `ViewHolder`. I will also wait to see if there are more suggestions. Thank you.